# Is the JFIF APP0 marker needed with /Filter /DCTDecode PDF stream?

Tags: pdf, jpeg

I'm generating a PDF file with a `/Filter /DCTDecode` (i.e. baseline JPEG) stream. My input JPEG file contains a JFIF APP0 marker, but no Exif markers. Is the JFIF marker necessarily to be included in the PDF stream for it to be valid, or can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PDF specification version 1.7 refers to [Technical Note #5116: Supporting the DCT Filters in PostScript Level 2](http://www.lprng.com/RESOURCES/ADOBE/5116.DCT_Filter.pdf), which explains that `/Filter /DCTDecode` ignores the JFIF marker (and several other markers) in the JPEG, and it respoects the Adobe-specific APPE marker, which has a `/ColorTransform` field, which can specify e.g. conversion from YCbCr (YUV) to RGB.

If the Adobe-specific APPE marker is missing from the JPEG stream, then the `/ColorTransform` field of the PDF image object can specify the transformation to be used. The default value is 1 if the image has 3 components, 0 otherwise. A value of 0 means no transformation, a value of 1 means transforming YUV to RGB or transforming YUVK to CMYK.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question that goes to the heart of the nature of JPEG. As to the PDF definition, I cannot give you an answer. For that, you would just have to try it and see if it works.

From the JPEG perspective, the stream should include an APPn marker that defines the file format. Without that marker, your stream does not say how the image should be reassembled.

Most decoders will assume a 1-component image is grayscale and a 3-component image is YCbCr if there is no file format marker. As this is the most common practice, stripping the APP0 marker MIGHT not cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I can't accept your answer, because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: PDF has its out-of-stream `/ColorSpace` definition (typically `/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB` or `/ColorSpace /DeviceGray`) for image objects. `/Filter /DCTDecode` converts a byte stream (a JPEG file) to another byte stream (each byte representing a color value). `/ColorSpace /DeviceRGB` is used for 3-component JPEGs, so the filter has to produce RGB triplets. I need to dig deeper on this.